# Chrome shows high cache storage use

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, cachestorage

I have been analyzing the cache storage use of complex application, when I realized that the stored image or script with certain content-length `N` actually takes `5N-10N` space in the cache storage.

Consider this sample: I am requesting image from OpenStreetMap via service worker and storing it in cache. There is only one image stored in cache. The Chrome version is the latest one (Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

This is the view of cache storage after refresh:
[image: cache_storage_view]

This is the view of clear cache tab:
[image]

So, the problem is that the image which has the size of `6.4KB` actually takes `13.8MB` of cache storage. Am I missing something?

The live example can be seen at https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/basic/ - less than `10KB` of scripts occupy almost `50KB` of cache storage.
[image]
[image]

So, **the question is**: how comes that when files are cached via service workers the space that they occupy significantly increases? I agree that the actual request weights more that actual response, but not **10 times more**.

Links that might be useful:

1. [Chrome dev tools showing high cache storage utilisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737006/chrome-dev-tools-showing-high-cache-storage-utilisation)
2. [Service Worker issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846914/service-worker-issues)
3. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=795134

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the case of OSM tiles, the high cache usage comes from opaque requests.

When you cache something from another domain, you are only allowed to cache it and not see the contents in any way. This makes the request opaque. You cannot fiddle with the contents in your code, only cache it, it's a black box. To avoid information leakage browsers implement padding when they cache the resource. For this reason an image of 100kb is reported to take 7mb of your cache, and the actual reported size differs from browser to browser.

This only means you will be able to cache a lot less opaque requests in the SW logic before a quota exceeded exception will be thrown. All of the cached requests – even if very small actually – take lots of (padded) space in the cache to avoid information leakage.

In the second case I think it's a bug.

Comment: Thank you a lot, you are totally right - removal of `{mode: "no-cors"}` did the trick.

Comment: In our case we were caching files with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header and thus - without `Content-Length` header. This can be also the case for lager cache space usage.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/progressive-web-apps/#opaque-responses
"In order to avoid leakage of cross-domain information, there's significant **padding** added to the size of an opaque response used for calculating storage quota limits.
for Google Chrome, this means that the minimum size that any single cached **opaque** response contributes to the overall storage usage is approximately **7 megabytes**."

Answer (score 0):

### With this trick I did the job:

if request mode is 'no-cors', I just create a new request with the original request url and return fetch of this new request

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    event.respondWith(caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {

        var newRequest = event.request;
        if (event.request.mode == 'no-cors') {
            newRequest = new Request(event.request.url);
        }

        return fetch(newRequest).then((fetchedResponse) => {

            // your logic for cache response. 
            // this time as 'no opaque' with lower quota storage
            cache.put(newRequest, fetchedResponse.clone());

            return  fetchedResponse;
        });
    }));
});
```

#### Now you can save "opaque" files with very lower storage quota

Comment: with thanks to @aleksandr, with the idea of removal of {mode: "no-cors"}, I did this trick and wrote this code wich solved my problem on this too