# PWA: assets are small in size, but chrome cache storage took around 500Mb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA app up and working, couple of days ago I started to add `ServiceWorker.js` file to my project in order to have an cache strategy up and working in my app. I'm using React and I use `serviceworker-webpack-plugin` in order to register my service worker.

As you might know `serviceworker-webpack-plugin` would give us a `serviceWorkerOption` global object in out `sw.js` file that includes all of our assets under `serviceWorkerOption.assets` key. so, I implemented cache flow in my Service worker file like below:

in install event I cache all my assets from `serviceWorkerOption.assets`:

```js
    caches.open(STATIC_CACHE_VERSION)
      .then(cache => {
        return cache.addAll(STATIC_CACHEABLE_ASSETS)
      })
      .catch( e => {
        console.log('[ sw ] cache cannot open cache', e)
      })
```

in fetch event I use **cache first , fallback to fetch** strategy and every thing looks fine so far.

---

### Problem

the problem raises in Chrome, where my cache storage is bumping up to 500mb, check image below:

[image]

as I use **cache first, fallback to fetch** it just added any new fetched image or asset to my `DYNAMIC_CACHEABLE_ASSETS` but as I see all of my assets in my public folder is around 4Mb and I don't think that would cause us any issue in cache side, with that considering what could be the problem? what can cause that amount of cache storage size?

Also I should note that this cache storage size is around 20Mb in normal Android device and that would be a mess to have around 500Mb cache size.

Comment: Are the assets you're caching from a different domain than the PWA?

Comment: no , its only my localhost

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49295113/chrome-shows-high-cache-storage-use